# Error retrieving data after using slug (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have problem accessing a page that is using slug url, previously when just using id it worked just fine.

Route : `Route::get('journal/{journalslug}', 'JournalController@show');`

URL : `href="{{ url('journal/' . $journal->journalslug) }}`

Controller :

```
public function show($journalslug) {
        $journal = Journal::where('journalslug','=',$journalslug)->get();
        return view('journal/show', compact('journal', $journal));
    }
```

View :

```
<div class="large-widget m30">
                    <div class="post-desc">
                        <h2 style="text-align: center;">{{ $journal->title }}</h2>
                        <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>
                                @foreach($journal->user as $item)
                                {{ $item->name }},
                                @endforeach
                        </strong></p>
                        <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Abstract :</strong></p>
                        <p>{!! $journal->abstract !!}</p>
                        <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="{{ asset('jurnal/' . $journal->file) }}" style="color : #00569d;">View Journal</a></p>
                    </div><!-- end post-desc -->
                </div><!-- end large-widget -->
```

Error :

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$title (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\2mark\resources\views\journal\show.blade.php)
```

I don't know what I did wrong, need your help guys, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to:

```
   $journal = Journal::where('journalslug','=',$journalslug)->first();
```

Comment: @AriandoMiller Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You should us [`firstOrFail()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) to make you solve your problem like this:

```
public function show($journalslug) {
    try {
        $journal = Journal::where('journalslug','=',$journalslug)->firstOrFail();
        return view('journal/show', compact('journal', $journal));
    } catch(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        // catch exception here
    }
    // return error page - no results found
}
```

> The `firstOrFail` methods will retrieve the first result
>   of the query; however, if no result is found, a
>   `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown.

This will ensure you if you won't found any of the results, hope this helps.